# CentOS 6.6 with Nginx 1.6.2 - Suddenly can't restart nginx - nginx: [emerg] open() “/usr/share/nginx/on” failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx, centos, php

This is a new install in which nginx previously started and stopped normally.  I believe this error arose after enabling server blocks which tested (nginx -t) successfully.  I then tried to restart nginx and received this error:

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/on" failed (13: Permission denied)`

The file "on" did not exist prior to the attempted restart.  It was just created and is empty.  When I restart php-fmp (successfully) and then try to restart nginx, the error changes to:

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

But again, when I run `nginx -t`, I get:

`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

I thought it might be a user issue but it is running as nginx:

`# ps -elf | grep nginx
5 S nginx     2774  2773  0  80   0 - 234152 skb_re 22:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
5 S nginx     2775  2773  0  80   0 - 234152 skb_re 22:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
5 S nginx     2776  2773  0  80   0 - 234152 skb_re 22:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
5 S nginx     2777  2773  0  80   0 - 234152 skb_re 22:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
5 S nginx     2778  2773  0  80   0 - 234152 skb_re 22:07 ?       00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
0 R root      2940  2472  0  80   0 - 25811 -      22:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nginx`

Also, using `sudo nginx -t` does not change anything.  What is also odd is the fact that there is a nginx.pid even though nginx is not running.  Deleting the pid file simply changes the error message back to:

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/on" failed (13: Permission denied)`

Deleting the `on` file makes no difference either.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are running as a superuser.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Comment: Actually `nginx` working on user `www-data` and it may be good idea to change owner of the folder to it.

Comment: I checked, the nginx user is `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Run getenforce to check SELinux mode. If it says Enforcing, then temporarily set the mode to Permissive by running setenforce 0, and see if your application works afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue

`nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websites.conf" failed (13: Permission denied) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36`.

The reason of the issue was provisioning configuration files over the SSH under specific user.
Here is how I fixed it (what I did besides `chmod`/`chown`).

If selinux is enabled (which is by default in Centos) then

```
ls -Z /path/to/file
```

must display "httpd_sys_content_t" as security context. If you encountering something like "user_home_t" you need to update this with running:

```
chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/file
```

After that restart "nginx" or "httpd" as usual.

Reference https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux